# How can appSettings.{environment}.json be loaded before environment is known? (AspNetCore)

Tags: asp.net-core, environment-variables

According to [microsoft blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/order-of-precedence-when-configuring-asp-net-core/) the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable is loaded in order:

1. appsettings.json file
2. appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json file
3. The local User Secrets File
4. Environment Variables
5. Command Line Arguments (or equivalently launchSettings.json)

and "The last key loaded wins".

**Questions:**

But how can the file appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json be loaded **before the final Environment is known**?

Can it happen that I set 'Staging' environment through command-line and appSettings.Development.json is loaded because during step 2 it is not yet known?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two sets of configuration for an ASP.NET Core application:

1. The configuration for the WebHost.
2. The configuration for the application itself.

First the WebHost configuration is built ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/WebHostBuilder.cs#L45)):

```cs
_config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
    .Build();
```

As the source code shows, the configuration for the WebHost uses *only* environment variables and only those that are prefixed with `ASPNETCORE_`. One of those environment variables is, unsurprisingly, `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`.

A little later down the line, an implementation of `IHostingEnvironment` is instantiated. This ends up using `_config` to retrieve a configuration setting named `environment`, which comes from the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable. If there is no such value, it defaults to `Production`.

Next up, the configuration for the application itself gets built. At step 2 in your question, the value of `env.EnvironmentName` is from the `IHostingEnvironment` I've already mentioned. If you were to set an environment value of e.g. `Staging` as a command-line argument, it would not change the value used in the WebHost configuration, as this applies only to the application configuration.

Andew Lock [goes into more detail](https://andrewlock.net/how-to-set-the-hosting-environment-in-asp-net-core/) about how this all works and also demonstrates how to configure the WebHost to use additional configuration sources.